# NGINX 443 is not binding but 80 redirects to https from the same file

Tags: nginx, web-hosting

I have been trying to configure a config which I believe to have been working on another server for static HTML serving. When I run NGINX it binds on port 80, yet does not show port 443 is being used.

The console does not show any noticeable errors and a config test does return a valid 'nginx.conf'

The layout i'm using in the other server is the same layout followed here
`/etc/nginx/conf.d/www.redacted.tk.conf`

```
    server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    server_name www.redacted.tk;

    # SSL
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.redacted.tk/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.redacted.tk/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.redacted.tk/fullchain.pem;

    # root directory (checked and does exist in /bin/bash on container)
    root /local/redacted/www-portfolio;

    # display html
    location / {
        try_files /index.html $uri $uri/ =404;
        include /etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;
    }
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.redacted.tk;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.redacted.tk$request_uri;
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I figured I should mention that when I check with netstat, it does not show 443 is bound. However it does show that 80 is bound and http://www.redacted.tk does redirect to https://www.redacted.tk which is refused.

**Edit**
Attempted to move flags around such as SSL back into the listen directive as a comment suggested. NGINX 1.15.5 is my current version.

Comment: what version of nginx are you using? I believe the preferred syntax is `listen          443 ssl;` now

Comment: I am using 1.15.5 - however I had it as `listen 443 ssl http2;` and it made no difference. I will try that now and let you know how it goes though.  That did not make a difference. It still just redirects to https but https is refused.   @WilliamChong